# Passing a list of itertools combinations to a function - map?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, statistics, python-itertools

Python Noob here, sorry.
I'm playing with Anscombe's quartet to explore the idea of how "fragile" correlations are by removing individual points (replacing with the group median) and then iterating through the data to return the Pearson r and p-value, then plotting both for every item in the source vector (Anscombe's Quartet was the inspiration). 
Iterating through and replacing a single value is easy enough:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import statistics
def new_list(x,y,n,replacex, replacey):
    '''Take 2 1D arrays (x and y) and replace item n with replacex and replacey respectively'''
    # First, copy the source arrays into the new arrays (newx, newy)
    newx=np.copy(x)
    newy=np.copy(y)
    #Now replace item n with the medians
    newx[n]=replacementx
    newy[n]=replacementy
    return(newx,newy)
#Initialise the dummy lists, assign the replacement values(medians), clear the temporary variables
newx=[] #temporary x list to run the new correlation
newy=[] #temporary y list to run the new correlation

p2values=[] #list of p values for the new correlations - this should change nearly every iteration
r2values=[] #list of r values for the new correlations - this should change nearly every iteration

replacementx=[] # single x value to be placed into the source list to run the new correlation. Currently using median
replacementy=[] # single y value to be placed into the source list to run the new correlation. Currently using median
#x,y values for one of Anscombe's Quartet as an example 
x=[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 19, 8, 8, 8]
y=[6.58, 5.76, 7.71, 8.84, 8.47, 7.04, 5.25, 12.50, 5.56, 7.91, 6.89]
replacementx = statistics.median(x)
replacementy = statistics.median(y)
for n in range(len(x)):
    newx,newy = new_list(x,y,n,replacementx,replacementy)
    r,p = stats.pearsonr(x,y)
    r2,p2 = stats.pearsonr(newx,newy)

    p2values.append(p2)
    r2values.append(r2)

    newx=[]
    newy=[]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Item number')
ax1.set_ylabel('Pearson r', color=color)
ax1.set_ylim(0,1)
ax1.plot(range(len(r2values)), r2values, range(len(rvalues)),rvalues, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('p value', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(range(len(p2values)),p2values, range(len(pvalues)), pvalues, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

plt.show()
```

Then I was thinking to generalise this I could somehow use itertools.combinations() to pass in the source data (Anscombe's quartet in this case) and the number of combinations of data points I'd like to test to see how fragile the correlation is. The farthest I'm able to get is to create the 'candidate' data points to remove from Anscombe's quartet as follows (for all combinations of 2 data points):

```
import itertools
#x,y values for one of Anscombe's Quartet as an example 
x=[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 19, 8, 8, 8]
y=[6.58, 5.76, 7.71, 8.84, 8.47, 7.04, 5.25, 12.50, 5.56, 7.91, 6.89]
data=list(zip(x,y))

replacement_candidates=list(itertools.combinations(data,2))
print(replacement_candidates)
```

I think I need to now **map()** the resulting list back across the simple new_list function which runs the correlation and returns the resulting Pearson r and p-values, and appends these to the p2values[] and r2values[] lists, but I'm getting horribly lost here, and would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance,
Rod

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured it out, so posting the code here in case this ever helps someone else. I was on the wrong track entirely.
The example here passes the 3rd member of Anscombe's quartet hard-coded in as the x,y values and an n of 3 (for all combinations of 3 values) but you can obviously swap these out for whatever you want. n = 1 shows that this member is fragile when the 8th item is replaced (r,p evaluate to nan). 
[sample output plot with n=1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGXoi.png)
I'll rewrite this as a function taking the x,y values and n, but since combinations can rapidly get out of hand, I want to put some measures in place to prevent out of memory errors and a progress bar or something (which is beyond me atm as this is basically my "Hello World" in Python)
The results are visualised along with dotted reference lines for the original r and p which helps me.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import statistics
from scipy import stats
# Initialise the source values - x,y, and n
# x,y are the source data for the correlation
# n is the number of items to figure out all combinations to replace within x,y

x=[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 19, 8, 8, 8]
y=[6.58, 5.76, 7.71, 8.84, 8.47, 7.04, 5.25, 12.50, 5.56, 7.91, 6.89]
n=3

r,p = stats.pearsonr(x,y)

appendtuple=()
p2values=[] #list of p-values for the new correlations - this should change nearly every iteration
r2values=[] #list of r values for the new correlations - this should change nearly every iteration
appendtuple=(statistics.median(x),statistics.median(y))
data=list(zip(x,y))
replacement_candidates=list(itertools.combinations(data,n))

def Diff(li1,li2):
    return(list(set(li1)-set(li2)))

for i in range(len(replacement_candidates)):
    a=[]
    a=Diff(data,replacement_candidates[i])
    for k in range(n):
        a.append(appendtuple)
    res_listx = [x[0] for x in a]
    res_listy= [y[1] for y in a]
    r2,p2 = stats.pearsonr(res_listx,res_listy)
    p2values.append(p2)
    r2values.append(r2)
    # print(res_listx,res_listy)
    # print(stats.pearsonr(res_listx,res_listy))

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Item number')
ax1.set_ylabel('Pearson r', color=color)
ax1.set_ylim(0,1)
ax1.plot(range(len(r2values)), r2values, range(len(rvalues)),rvalues, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

plt.hlines(r,0,len(p2values),linestyles='dotted',label='r', color='tab:red')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('p value', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(range(len(p2values)),p2values, range(len(pvalues)), pvalues, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
plt.hlines(p,0,len(p2values),linestyles='dotted',label='r', color='tab:blue')
plt.show()
```